# How to represent a blueprint with clickable areas in Android

Tags: android

I need a direction how to achieve the following functionality: I have a blueprint that contains specific zones that can be clicked. I also need the blueprint to be zoomable (respectively the clickable zones). Is it better to use 2D graphics, plain Java code or XML representation, or other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in widget or functionality that supports this. You probably have to write custom code to do handle zooming/panning/clickable area resizing. This tutorial might be a good start on that: http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/

But you'll have to handle the size modifications on the clickable areas yourself upon zooming.

Maybe consider using OpenGl for this, tho that would be an overkill I think.

Comment: If we put aside the zoom functionality, what is your recommendation for representing image with clickable zones?

Comment: The images you'd like to display are bigger than most screens I presume. In that case, I'd go with a custom View wiget, handling the panning action properly. The linked tutorial has some related tutorials on that site which describe how to implement panning if I remember correctly, so you can consider that. An easier way to go would be to display the image in an ImageView widget, embedding it in a HorizontalScrollView, and embedding that in a ScrollView. It would handle vertical and horizontal scrolling - but in a terrible way, just try it.